# Is $\sin(440\cdot2\pi x)+\sin(440\cdot 2^{1/4}\cdot2\pi x)+\sin(440\cdot2^{1/2}\cdot2\pi x)$ periodic?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, periodic-functions

Can anyone help me to determine whether the function below is periodic or not? If it is periodic, can anyone tell me how to find the period.

$$y=\sin(440\cdot2\pi x)+\sin(440\cdot 2^{1/4}\cdot2\pi x)+\sin(440\cdot2^{1/2}\cdot2\pi x)$$

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: No, the function is not periodic.

Comment: Hint: If $y(x)$ is periodic, then so does $y'(x)$. Can you find a non-zero $x$ with $y'(x) = y'(0)$?

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on Ajay's quick comment: that function is not periodic due to being the sum of three continuous periodic functions with incommensurate periods (*i.e.* at least one of the ratios between the different periods is irrational) such that all of the possible sums of these functions are non-constant (*i.e.* $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$, $\lambda f_1 + \mu f_2$, $\lambda f_1 + \mu f_3$, $\lambda f_2 + \mu f_3$ and $\lambda f_1 + \mu f_2 + \nu f_3$ are all non-constant; without this condition, you can easily create "degenerate" counterexamples, for example by picking $f_2 := -f_1$, in which case $f_1 + f_2 + f_3$ is periodic iff $f_3$ is periodic). See Theorem $1$ in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.03752v1) for reference.

There are quite a few posts on MSE for the particular case of a sum of *two* continuous periodic functions but I couldn't seem to find a satisfying one for the generalisation to multiple functions, to my dismay. But oh well.